# Changing a optional property value with the use of a default initializer in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, initialization

What is wrong with the line of code when I set the variable called item2 and why isn't this initialization possible to do if the name property is optional?

```
class ShoppingListItem {
    var name: String?
    var quantity = 1
    var purchased = false
}

var item = ShoppingListItem()
var item2 = ShoppingListItem(name:"Orange Juice")

print(item.name)
print(item2.name)
```

Comment: Regarding the optional: In real life how many nameless shopping list items are there? ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this code

```
ShoppingListItem(name:"Orange Juice")
```

you are invoking an initializer of `ShoppingListItem` that does not exist.

So just define the initializer into the class

```
class ShoppingListItem {
    var name: String?
    var quantity = 1
    var purchased = false

    init(name:String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    init() { }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> [Memberwise Initializers for Structure Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID213)
>
> Structure types automatically receive a memberwise initializer if they
>   do not define any of their own custom initializers. Unlike a default
>   initializer, the structure receives a memberwise initializer even if
>   it has stored properties that do not have default values.
>
> The memberwise initializer is a shorthand way to initialize the member
>   properties of new structure instances. Initial values for the
>   properties of the new instance can be passed to the memberwise
>   initializer by name.
>
> The example below defines a structure called Size with two properties
>   called width and height. Both properties are inferred to be of type
>   Double by assigning a default value of 0.0.
>
> The Size structure automatically receives an init(width:height:)
>   memberwise initializer, which you can use to initialize a new Size
>   instance:

```
struct Size {
    var width = 0.0, height = 0.0
}

let twoByTwo = Size(width: 2.0, height: 2.0)
```

Comment: Please add something of your own to this post.

Comment: Every answer is straight from the Swift documentation. Even the question's code is in the documentation.  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html

Comment: The accepted answer uses the code from the question plus an explanation written by the poster. This is also the documentation about structs; the code in question uses a class.

Comment: While technically accurate, it is not immediately clear how this relates to the question. This answer could be improved by editing the example code to correspond with the code in the question, or explaining the quoted documentation more clearly, in terms which are relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you have to add initializer, or set a name after initialization:

```
class ShoppingListItem {
    var name: String?
    var quantity = 1
    var purchased = false
}

var item2 = ShoppingListItem()
item2.name = "Orange Juice"

print(item2.name)
```

Comment: Actually you are now assigning an empty `String` to `name` to represent the absence of value. You should always use `nil` to represent the no value concept.

Comment: Having methods or not has nothing to do with choosing `class` vs. `struct` in Swift.

Comment: Yes, I agree, with struct it was a bad idea. I changed my answer.